# Passing the values to multiple components on click

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I have 2 components called `list` and `details` which are placed like this:

[image]

`list` is having list of customers and `details` is used to display particular customer details(i,e name , age....) as shown in the image.

There is an button called `edit` in `details` component as shown in image, on clicking this button i am calling an component called `edit` in dialog window.

In `edit` component.I want to display the same data(i,e name,age...) displayed on the `display` component.like this:

[image]

In order to perform `CRUD` operation. I have tried by give input as given in the `details` component.But i am unable achieve this.

Stackblitz [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-vguhhp?file=app/edit/edit.component.ts)

Updated Stackblitz [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-2fv5qk?file=app/customer/customer.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` here something like

change openDialog method to pass data to dialog

```
 public openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditComponent> = this.dialog.open(EditComponent, {
      width: '61.6vw',   height: '100vh', position: { right: '0'},data:this.contact
    });
  }
```

then in edit component inject MAT_DIALOG_DATA

```
constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }
```

and in your edit component html bind value to this data [Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-imscur)

[Official doc](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component-)

Comment: My requirement little change: I am using `details` component as generic component. So i am writing code in `customer` component to open dialog window. Please see the updated **link**. and make changes.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-hghiie

Answer (score 1):

Create a shared service(say Global service). Then pass the value of selected contact like

`<button mat-stroked-button (click)="openDialog(contact)" >Edit</button>`

now inside make you openDiaglo function like

```
public openDialog(con:any): void {
    this.global.name = contact.name;
    rhis.global.age = contact.age;
    const dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditComponent> = this.dialog.open(EditComponent, {
    width: '61.6vw',   height: '100vh', position: { right: '0'},
    });
  }
```

now inside edit component , you can assign the `global.name` and `global.age` values to the local variables.